# Drawing Rectangle in Java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw a rectangle. But I am not sure how, it paints in certain panel. Would like to see an example for, How I can supply the panel and position for drawing the rectangle. I have the following template, I would like to see what modifications I need to make to use this class to draw rectangle on any Panels. My intention is to use panels width, and heights and add a rectangle to that position. Goal is to be able to use this class any where with any JPanels.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;    
import javax.swing.JPanel;    

public class DrawRectangle{

    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color color;
    private JPanel panel;

    public DrawRectangle(JPanel panel, int startX, int startY, int width, int height, Color color) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
            this.panel = panel; 
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.fillRect(this.startX, this.startY, this.width, this.height);
        g.drawRect(this.startX, this.startY, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a complete examples that draws rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Graphics2D class it is meant for exactly what you are trying to do and is better suited for drawing than the regular `paintComponent` method. You can read about how to use Graphics2D [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Firstly note that you cannot have a `Graphics2D` object without casting it from a `Graphics` object like I did here `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;`.

This is an example that should help you to get started, keep in mind I'm using absolute layout so no layout manager. This is code I was using to create a blackjack game so thats why things are names are not generic.

Also I added smoothing so your shapes with Graphics2D will look really nice and the methods center the shapes on screen which will probably work well with your JPanels.

Notice how I created specific methods for the Graphics2D objects I wanted to draw and then drew them using the Graphics class. That seemed to work the best for me so that my `paintComponent` wasn't just littered with endless repeated code. `frame` in my code was getting the width and height of the `JFrame` I had the `JPanel` in so for you simply refer to the `JPanel` you would have it in instead.

```
class DrawTable extends JPanel
{

    DrawTable()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Looks good to me pal!");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Setup background
        drawRectangle(g, Color.BLACK,
                frame.getWidth() / 2, frame.getHeight() / 2,
                frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

        // Create table at center
        drawRectangle(g, new Color(206, 187, 158),
                frame.getWidth() / 4, frame.getHeight(), //left table leg
                50, 600);
        drawRectangle(g, new Color(206, 187, 158),
                frame.getWidth() / 1.5, frame.getHeight(), //right table leg
                50, 600);
        drawEllipse(g, new Color(153, 154, 104),
                frame.getWidth() / 2, frame.getHeight() / 2, //Draws outer circle
                1200, 400);
        drawEllipse(g, new Color(53, 101, 77),
                frame.getWidth() / 2, frame.getHeight() / 2, //Draws inner circle
                1125, 350);
    }

    private void drawEllipse(Graphics g, Color color, double x, double y, double width, double height) //centers ellipse
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        double centerX = (double) x - width / 2;
        double centerY = (double) y - height / 2;
        Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(centerX, centerY, width, height);
        RenderingHints render = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        render.put(
                RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.setRenderingHints(render);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fill(ellipse);
        g2.draw(ellipse);
    }

    private void drawRectangle(Graphics g, Color color, double x, double y, double width, double height) //centers rectangle
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        double centerX = (double) x - width / 2;
        double centerY = (double) y - height / 2;
        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(centerX, centerY, width, height);
        RenderingHints render = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        render.put(
                RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.addRenderingHints(render);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore help!

Comment: "Firstly note that you cannot have a Graphics2D object without casting it from a Graphics object like I did here Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;" -- this is not strictly true

Comment: When overriding paintComponent(GRAPHICS g) it is. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Agree, when you get the `Graphics` object from the JVM, such as within `paint`, `paintComponent`, or `paintComponents`, then the Graphics2D object can often be obtained by casting. One can also be obtained directly from a BufferedImage by way of its `.createGraphics()` method, and then this image can be drawin within the `paintComponent` method. Also, your code appears to be repurposed GUI code, one that won't compile due to residual lines of code that in the current context have no meaning (or variable declaration).

Comment: I think I explained pretty well what the variables are for and they explain themselves, `frame.getHeight()`. However, I may edit my answer to include a bit more of an explanation for `RenderingHints`. It will definitely compile if op just follows my my code and I have it inheriting from the base class op asked for. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: ? I edited my post a while ago to remove that. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Fair enough, anything else that I should add to make my answer more clear for op? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: No, I would only add that I like the way that the OP has arranged things better than how your code does things. You've got your drawing code as hardcoded methods of the component or view code, the code that extends GUI components and that does the actual drawing, while the OP has made their DrawRectangle class separate from the component class. Their code has basically "extracted out" some of the logic of the code, the model code, from the view, allowing for lower coupling and greater ease of debugging and enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to modify the JPanel of interest in order to use that code by:

- Overriding its paintComponent method
- First calling the super's paintComponent method in your override
- And then drawing your own DrawRectangle class's paint method
- If you want to be able to draw multiple rectangles, then give the JPanel a `List<DrawRectangle>` and draw those in a for loop within paintComponent

For example, for one rectangle:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private DrawRectangle drawRectangle;

    public DrawingPanel(DrawRectangle drawRectangle) {
        this.drawRectangle = drawRectangle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (drawRectangle != null) {
            drawRectangle.paint(g);
        }
    }
}
```

and for many rectangles:

```
public class DrawingManyRectPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<DrawRectangle> drawRectangles;

    public DrawingManyRectPanel(List<DrawRectangle> drawRectangles) {
        this.drawRectangles = drawRectangles;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (drawRectangles != null) {
            for (DrawRectangle rectangle : drawRectangles) {
                rectangle.paint(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In these classes, the constructor is overridden to allow injection of rectangles into the class via constructor call. For the second class, I'd also add a method that allows addition of further rectangles:

```
public void addRectangle(DrawRectangle rectangle) {
    drawRectangles.add(rectangle);
    repaint();
}
```

similar for removing rectangles

---

An alternate way to do this, if you don't plan to remove rectangles or modify the ones already drawn, is to draw them in a BufferedImage, and then draw that image in the drawing JPanel's paintComponent method.